# document not compiling with custom .cls

Tags: compiling

I copied my thesis from my work computer to write on it from home. But the compiler is telling me it can not open the style file even though its in the same folder as the `.tex` file. It compiles fine on my work pc. I copied the whole folder without changing the file structure. 
Since I don't really understand the error messages (since they are way to unintuitive for me) I'm not sure what the problem is. It tell me 'I couldn't open style file uni.bst' Do i have to put it somewhere else or install it? I did neither on my work computer. So why is it not working here? It is compiling simple documents just fine. So I guess the problem is with the `.cls` file.

Comment: a .bst file is not a .cls file. So if your error is complaining about a missing .bst check if it is there. (bst is a bibtex style).

Comment: ah cool. i removed the inclusion of the literature and its at least compiling now. Still dont understand why. But I can work on the text now. thanks ;D

Comment: The `I couldn't open style file uni.bst` message suggests that `uni.bst` (a BibTeX bibliography style file) is not available on your computer. You probably copied the `.cls` file and `.tex` file from your work PC but forgot to also take `uni.bst` with you (chances are that file lives somewhere else and not in the document folder, maybe it was installed system-wide). I couldn't find a `uni.bst` on a quick search on the web, so I suppose it is something that belongs to your custom class/template.

Comment: If you are back at your work PC you should be able to find the file `uni.bst` if you type `kpsewhich uni.bst` into the command line/terminal provided it was installed and does not just live in the document folder. The command should return the place where the file resides and you can copy it from there into the same directory as your `.tex` file.